What information about followed posts can moderators access?
When the "follow posts" feature was introduced, an SE staff member commented that "Post follows are private." Similarly, the "save posts" feature announcement stated that "[Save] notes are private to you, as are all of your lists and saves." Based on this information, I've been using both features with the belief that my followed and saved posts were not visible to others, including moderators.
However, a recent interaction with a site moderator has made me question this assumption. During a meta discussion about how I was encountering deleted questions that weren't mine (which typically only 10K users can search for if they're their own), I mentioned that I had followed or bookmarked them. To my surprise, a moderator responded that "In case [I didn't] know, [they] can see that follow list" and noted there weren't many questions I claimed to be following.
Can moderators really see my follow list? If so, do they have access to all of it or just a portion? Is moderator access to this information logged (similar to how moderator access to users' names, email addresses, and IP information is logged)? What about posts I've unfollowed—can moderators see my follow/unfollow history? The information I've gathered from the above meta posts suggests these lists are private, so I'm a bit perplexed by the situation.
Have I misunderstood the privacy settings of the follow and save features? What information about followed posts can moderators access?

Moderators can see followed posts just like how users see them from their profile.
From the release announcement,

We are still planning on two more related releases:

Follows profile tab and question listing filter: [...] Users (with the exception of moderators and authorized staff) will not be able to see this information about other users (nor will it be made public in the API, SEDE, or data dumps).
[...]

Update (June 11, 2020): The user profile tab and the rename of Favorites to Bookmarks have been released.

There's no guardrail (e.g. by hiding and clicking) before showing the followed posts list. As such, loading this list (e.g. automatically in the Activity page) is not logged in the user history, since followed posts are not considered PII as well.
In addition, mods cannot take actions on their follow list (e.g. cannot unfollow). Since there is no "following" history, mods cannot know the user's following past actions. Finally, mods cannot track back who follows a post from the post directly.

"Saves" are completely private though, nothing is exposed.

Thanks for clarifying. This raises some privacy concerns that weren't apparent from the feature's introduction.

@galacticninja I think you missed the release announcement...

Apparently, I did. ☺️ Still raises some privacy concerns, though.

Do you know if moderator access to this information is logged (similar to how moderator access to users' names, email addresses, and IP information is logged)?

@galacticninja not logged, since these are not considered PII.
